# Boolean Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

Why can't we assign values to a boolean array in Java without using the new keyword?

For example:

```
boolean[ ] aryBools = {true, false, true, false};
```

Comment: The syntax you provided is completely valid. I checked and it compiles in Java 15. Which version are you using?

Comment: you _CAN_ write `boolean[] arrayBools = {true, false, true, false};`.

Comment: What do you mean? Have you tried to compiled the given example? It is completely valid. I suspect it is compiled to the same bytecode as new boolean[]{true,false,true,false}, but that doesn't mean we have to write it that way.

Comment: Hint: whenever you want to ask why something won't compile, try compiling the *exact* code you're posting, and include the exact error message (copy/paste) in the question. Following that guideline would have let you see that you *can* do this, and then you wouldn't have asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

Java is typed. You can't make an array of 'whatever', and java is not going to attempt to figure out what you meant. Imagine you wrote: `{new Apple(), new Pear()}`, should that be a `Fruit[]`, `Object[]`, or `SuperMarketbestseller[]`?

Thus, the syntax is `new boolean[] {true, false, true, false}`.

There is only one exception: If and only if creating the initializing expression for a newly declared variable/field of an array type, you can omit it. So specifically:

```
boolean[] b = {true, false, true, false};
```

is legal java, has always been legal java, and if it's not legal in whatever you are doing, then you don't have java, or more likely, you have a file that isn't syntactically valid. So get rid of it, and make a new file, and try it:

```
class Example {
    boolean[] test = {true, false};
}
```

and you will find that this compiles fine. But, that shortened syntax works ONLY if assigning directly to a variable *declaration* (not just `test = {true, false};`, no, `boolean[] test = {true, false};`).

Comment: "If and only if assigning directly to a variable/field of an array type" this is misleading: `boolean[] b; b = {};` is assigning to a variable directly (not quite sure what an indirect assignment would be). You can only use array initializer syntax in the *initializer* of the variable, that is, in the variable's declaration.

Comment: The followup paragraph highlights this.

Comment: Then say: "if and only declaring a variable" when you first mention it, because it's not valid in assignments.

Comment: answer updated.